# How can I do a countif for a value in one column where the values for another column are unique?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
A    B      C
ID  Charge  Value
01  100     40
01  100     40
01  200     20
02  100     40
```

If I have a spreadsheet linking to the above spreadsheet and I wanted to lookup the number of times `01` had a Charge and did =countif(A:A,'01') it would say 3. However, I'm looking for how many times `01` had a unique charge. In the above we see multiple rows for 100. I want the answer to show 2, because they had 2 unique charge IDs.

How can I just get a count for `01` for unique charges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel365 you can try-

```
=CountA(Unique(Filter(B2:B5,A2:A5="01")))
```

Comment: Since B is numeric I would do `COUNT` only because Filter always returns something, either an error or an array.  If an error when there is no match found `COUNTA` will still return 1.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, you are right. For numbers `COUNT()` is appropriate. For texts it is better to use `SUM(--(Unique(Filter(B2:B5,A2:A5="01"))<>""))`

Answer (score 2):

If one does not have Office 365:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="01")/(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B5,A:A,"01")+(A2:A5<>"01")))
```

[image]

OR:

```
 =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A5="01",B2:B5),B2:B5)>0))
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version it will require that one confirms with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If the data is text and not numeric then we need to use this version if using FREQUENCY:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A5="01",MATCH(B2:B5,B:B,0)),MATCH(B2:B5,B:B,0))>0))
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version it will require that one confirms with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]