# count the unique cell values based on multiple conditio

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I was able to count all the values using countifs, but I would like to count only the unique values in the cell.

Condition: If A value matches with K column values and L column values are completed or In progress, then count unique values in column I

EX: K2, K3, K4 matches the code ABP in A2, then it should return the count as 2

count abc@xyz.com as 1 if the status in any cells in L is completed or In progress.
Do not count mnp@xyz.com and gh@xyzcom because the status is enrolled

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67206081)

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: In your example also K5 matches and without K5 it would result into 1 unique value for column I: `abc@xyz.com`. If you include the match of K5 you have 2 unique values in column I: `abc@xyz.com, def@xyz.com`. Is that correct?

Comment: @P.b yes, that's correct. I don't want to count K6, K7, and K8 as the status is Enrolled. I want the count of completed OR in progress (not AND), if the code matches

Comment: @Harun24HR Microsoft 365 MSO(16.0.13901.20366) 32-bit